# Multiply Tensorflow sequential layer by fixed integers

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to make a simple reinforcement learning model that makes one of three decisions, `A`, `B`, or `C`.  However, `C` will be effectively a "do nothing" decision.  Because `C` will never result in an action, it should always have a value of 0.

So all I want to do is multiply the 3 output nodes by 1, 1, 0.  That is, I want to do an element-wise multiplication by a `[1,1,0]` tensor so that the `A` and `B` nodes retain their values from the previous layer and the `C` node always has a value of 0.

I see that there's a `Multiply` layers class, which I think might work, but I'm seeing examples with the functional API.  Is there another way to do this with the Sequential API?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be really simple.  I just used a Lambda layer to multiply the previous output layer by the multiplication vector.

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)) # previous output layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * [1,1,0])) # new output layer
```

It appears to be working correctly.